# How do I remove the first occurence of a substring in string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, substring

How can I remove the first occurence of a given substring?

I have:

```
phrase = "foobarfoo"
```

and, when I call:

```
phrase.some_method_i_dont_know_yet ("foo")
```

I want the phrase to look like `barfoo`.

I tried with `delete` and `slice` but the first removes all the occurrences but the second just returns the slice.

Comment: Thank you for this question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `sub!` to substitute what you are trying to find with ""(nothing), thereby deleting it:

```
phrase.sub!("foo", "")
```

The !(bang) at the end makes it permanent. `sub` is different then `gsub` in that `sub` just substitutes the first instance of the string that you are trying to find whereas `gsub` finds all instances.

Answer (score 2):

[`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-sub) will do what you want.  `gsub` is the global version that you're probably already familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String#[]` method:

```rb
phrase["foo"] = ""
```

For comparison, in my system this solution is 17% faster than `String#sub!`